# How to increase the java heap size in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans-7

I am trying to build a lexicon trie of almost 110000 words in java in netbeans. My code is running fine but it gives an Exception as follows:

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3209)
at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:215)
at java.nio.HeapCharBuffer.toString(HeapCharBuffer.java:542)
at java.nio.CharBuffer.toString(CharBuffer.java:1157)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.toMatchResult(Matcher.java:232)
at java.util.Scanner.match(Scanner.java:1270)
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1517)
at lexiconbuild.model.Lexicon.<init>(Lexicon.java:29)
at lexiconbuild.model.LexiconBuild.main(LexiconBuild.java:17)
Java Result: 1
```

I was wondering if someone could help me with increasing the java heap space in netbeans.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can set it in NetBeans in the project properties -> Run -> VM options

1. Right click on your project "**Properties**"
2. Select "**Run**" category.
3. Enter your arguments(**-Xmx512m**) in the "**VM Options**" text box.

Example: Putting -Xmx512m in the "VM Options" text box gives 512Mb maximum heap size to your Java program.

Comment: NetBeans changed sometime in the last 4 years, and "Build and Run" doesn't have anywhere intuitive to put commandline arguments now. Only some predefined targets.

Answer (score 39):

if you want to change it for netbeans it self you can change it from this file:

```
netbeans.conf
```

you will find it in netbeans folder under /etc

and there is two parameters for the heap

Xms - the initial size of the heap.

Xmx - max java heap size

it using the default, you just have to add it there and try to add them both.

and also don't forget to add those to  netbeans_default_options when you change the XMX

```
-J-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -J-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
```

so netbeans_default_options will be something like that:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms512m -J-Xmx1024m -J-XX:PermSize=256m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -J-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -J-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled"
```

Comment: Majed, your solution helped me at some point but now that I have an even bigger file when I change the values of Xms and Xmx to 1024 and 2048 I get an error of 'Could not reserve enough space for 2097152kb object heap' any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

In the run configuration you should set Java VM option `-Xmx512m` or other that limits the maximum size of the Java VM to 512M. You can always experiment with other values. You are only limited with physical memory used by the OS.