# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

While running my java code i got an error like this.please help me to over this error...i want to know the maximum size of an **STRING ARRAY.**..

Comment: See this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15460779/how-to-increase-the-java-heap-size-in-netbeans

Comment: Limit of the Integer number

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3039805/1255746) looks useful.

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem is here - are you actually running out of memory in your real application? If so, have you tried changing the maximum heap size? Or did you only get this error while trying to create deliberately-huge string arrays?

Answer (score 2):

The maximum length  for any array at the moment is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`  which is approximately 2G for both 64 and 32 bit VM.

The reason for this that the `new` operator accepts `int` as length parameter (for instance `new int[intLength]`). There are proposals to allow `long` in a future release of Java.

If your array/String's length is less than Integer.MAX_VALUE, try to increase your max heap size - for instance: 
`-Xmx4g` where 4g means 4GB

Answer (score 1):

the Array size is limited only with the heap size. to increase the heap allocation for your program use the

```
-Xmx1500m
```

as a jvm argument when running you application.

```
java -Xmx2000m .......
```

You can go up to 4GB for 32 bit JAVA and more on 64bit.

Comment: *"You can go up to 4GB for 32 bit JAVA"* - While technically correct, Windows will only allow you to allocate 3gb - just saying ;)

Comment: It's not correct - you cannot allocate a single array longer than Integer.MAX_VALUE using `new`

Comment: Good thinking if the question is regarding number of elements, if it is regarding the size of the array still correct.