# StackOverflowError to my recursive calls in Java

Tags: java, jvm, stack-overflow

i'm getting `StackOverflowError` to my recursive call:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at Test.trailMngr(Test.java:112)
        at Test.trailMngr(Test.java:115)
        at Test.trailMngr(Test.java:115)
        at Test.trailMngr(Test.java:115)
        at Test.trailMngr(Test.java:115)
        ...
    Java Result: 1
```

Is there a way to fix this without changing the code?

The only way i can think of is making it a non-recursive method.

Everything else in the code is working fine in smaller input sizes-- i'll avoid the change if possible (although i'm not hopeful).

Not well-familiar with how Java behaves on these things.

TIA.

Comment: Are the recursive calls terminating? You can increase thread stack space size. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700459/how-to-increase-the-java-stack-size) and [other related questions/answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030120/java-default-stack-size).

Comment: its very difficult to answer your question with the inputs given

Comment: I think your recursive code is not terminating gracefully. But if your sure about the terminating logic, you should consider increasing the stack size by -Xss option.

Comment: @SamDJava i'm running an exponential alg. and I don't think I made a mistake on the logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're not dealing with infinite recursion, you can increase the stack size using the command-line `Xss` parameter:

```
java -Xss8m Test
```

This is the amount of memory allocated for every thread's internal use. Sizes can be specified in bytes (`-Xss8`), kilobytes (`-Xss8k`), megabytes (`-Xss8m`) or gigabytes (`-Xss8g`). Note that setting this to a high value will obviously increase your memory usage.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen - k let me try this

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Don't know how the thread being in or outside a pool plays into this. Please clarify.

Comment: Just what you mentioned about increased memory usage if you're holding on to X thread objects.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen where do I get this done on NetBeans?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15460816/3558960). It's about setting the heap size, but the principle is the same.