# How to create a very large 2D Matrix in Java?

Tags: java

I have tried the following way:

int[][] Matrix=new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE-5][Integer.MAX_VALUE-5];

But I get this exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.

What i mean is i want to store a matrix of nxn size where n is around 500000, but my Netbeans shows out of memory exception for just 10000, how would i increase the memory

Comment: There is no way you have enough memory for that array ...

Comment: Do you have a requirement to handle such a big data chunk using Java? Or does it have to be "A" HL language?

Comment: Is there are problem to be solved or do you just fiddle with java?

Comment: This would require about 16 Petabyte = around 16,400 Exabyte = 16,700,000 Terabyte = 17,200,000,000 Gigabyte. This number cannot even be displayed in (signed) 64-bit integers!

Comment: Not to mention how long would it take to fill that array...

Comment: Do the math: 500000 x 500000 x 4 bytes is ?

Comment: In response to your edit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15460779/how-to-increase-the-java-heap-size-in-netbeans

Although the array you're trying to create is still unfeasible. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I wanna store an adjacency matrix of those many nodes

Comment: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/44sp/NYC.txt

Comment: The ABOVE FILE is the input file with 264346 nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at a [sparse matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix), which allows you to process huge matrices containing only relatively few values.

Examples of a sparse matrix format:

- CSR (Compressed sparse row) -- stores non-zero elements in contiguous array with another two arrays containing column indices and pointers to row beginnings
- COO (Coordinate list) -- stores array of tuples (row, column, value)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you so much. Long live Erbureth :)

Answer (score 4):

There is no way that array will fit in memory.

Integer.MAX_VALUE is 2^31.

Two dimensions means storing 2^62 integers at 4 bytes each.

Answer (score 1):

For 10000 x 10000 set your heap size to 512MB: `java -Xmx512m`. 
For 500000 x 500000 set your heap size to about 1TB: `java -Xmx1000000m`. You might want to wait a few years for computers with that amount of memory to become available for the general public...