# java.lang.outOfMemory java heap space

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

I am new to Java and I create a project in Java using NetBeans 8.0. Now I 
    want make a .jar file from my project. But when I click on Clean and 
    Build option, after few minutes it displays an error like this. 
    The system is out of resources.
    Consult the following stack trace for details.
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    My project runs perfectly and in working condition it displays the above 
    error  only when I want to clean and build the project. Or guide how to make
    a .exe file without a .jar file.
    Please help me it makes my life very difficult. 
    Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make .exe file from .jar file You can use the ExcelsiorJET to convert jar files into native codes. Its a very good software to do it but i will suggest you, use it if you want to publish your software commericailly.
It also provide a high level obfuscation to your codes.

If you want to read about it more  [Official site of ExcelsiorJET](http://www.excelsiorjet.com/)

**and about java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:**

That means your codes are using more memory(heap space) than default heap size set to JVM. One more thing it also indicates that there may be some memory leaks in your codes so try to patch them also ..

To solve this problem .. you should go to this link [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15460779/how-to-increase-the-java-heap-size-in-netbeans)
i don't want to repeat all things so visit this link

Comment: Hello Harpeet, if i use the try, catch block and leave the catch block empty like this try{ some code }catch (Exception ex){ empty }. Is the empty block leaks the memory? please guide me