# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError Java heap space solution (Netbeans and Tomcat - Spring - Hibernate)

Tags: java, arrays, hibernate, netbeans, tomcat8

I am using Netbeans IDE and Tomcat server. When executing hibernate call , i am getting error like this.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.ByteArrayTypeDescriptor.wrapBytes(ByteArrayTypeDescriptor.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.ByteArrayTypeDescriptor.wrap(ByteArrayTypeDescriptor.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.ByteArrayTypeDescriptor.wrap(ByteArrayTypeDescriptor.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2969)
```

How to overcome this error? Give me a clear indication what should i do.
I saw some solutions but those were not clear to me.

---

after configuring (Netbeans) its Ok. No Hibernate error . But now showing -

```
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Array.java:75)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.ArrayMutabilityPlan.deepCopyNotNull(ArrayMutabilityPlan.java:43)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.MutableMutabilityPlan.deepCopy(MutableMutabilityPlan.java:52)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.deepCopy(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:321)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.deepCopy(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:317)
at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.deepCopy(TypeHelper.java:67)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you get rid of the error??

Comment: @SachinSarawgi not yet.. New error found. see edited

Comment: Dont down vote . If you are so exper then just leave it @down voter

Comment: I think their is some error in your coding part. Could you please post full error stack or this is the only error stack its showing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it in NetBeans in the project properties -> Run -> VM options

1. Right click on your project "Properties"
2. Select "Run" category.
3. Enter your arguments(-Xmx512m) in the "VM Options" text box.

Example: Putting -Xmx512m in the "VM Options" text box gives 512Mb maximum heap size to your Java program.

here is the full answer [heap space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15460779/how-to-increase-the-java-heap-size-in-netbeans)

Comment: i have 4 GB ram.  can i use -Xmx2048m ?

Comment: yes 2GB is sufficient. but you can also go with 1GB